Call print server from Azure
We have a print server in the company domain and I want to call printing via the print server from a Blazor Server Application in Azure. These printers are label printers. I know there is a PrintServer class to queue a print job but this is available only for .NET Desktop 8.
Is there any way to queue a print job from Azure side? Let's say Azure can access this print server. Would it work if I write a console application which is running on a VM and Blazor App can call/trigger this console application to send document to a printer?

You need to find out exactly what protocols/schemes your LAN print-server supports. Do you know the name+model, etc?

@Dai Yes, Zebra and Datamax printers, multiple models (e.g.: Datamax I-4208 or Datamax H-4310).
